# Listed As User "Uknown" in Sublime repository?

Tags: svn, version-control, repository, system-administration

Using Subversion as my source control, I set up a project last week and have been checking in code.  Just realized that I am listed as "unknown" under the User header in sublime.

Everyone that checks in/out of that project is also listed as unknown.

Anyone know how to correct this without deleting and starting over?

Comment: When checking in any file, svn must have asked for some username/password. What have you provided there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you enabled anonymous commits on your repository. This can be changed in the `conf/svnserve.conf` file of the repository on the server.

You can find more information in the [SVN documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06s03.html).